# Retrieving contents of ListBoxItem with Foreach

Tags: c#, wpf

This is the setup of my `ListView` and a `textbox` to display the items being selected as string.

```
<ListView Name="myListView" SelectionChanged="myListBox_SelectionChanged_1" SelectionMode="Multiple">
    <ListViewItem Content="Item 1"/>
    <ListViewItem Content="Item 2"/>
    <ListViewItem Content="Item 3"/>
</ListView>
<TextBox Name="tb" Width="140" Height="30" Margin="20"/>
```

This is the line which successfully output the value of `ListViewItem`.

```
string output = ((ListViewItem)myListView.SelectedItem).Content.ToString();
/// output: Item 1
```

But I have no idea how to implement it in the `foreach` loop

```
foreach (ListViewItem item in myListView.SelectedItems)
{
    string output = item.ToString();
    tb.AppendText(output);
}
```

The foreach loop currently outputs:

```
System.Windows.Controls.ListViewItem: {the ListViewItem value}
```

I want to get rid of the `System.Windows...` in front.

I have tried to place this line inside the `foreach` loop, but it only outputs value of the first `ListViewItem` selected.

```
string output = ((ListBoxItem)myListView.SelectedItem).Content.ToString();
```

The expected output should be `Item 1 Item 2...` inside the textbox.

Comment: You have the ListBoxItem in your loop i think you need  `item.Content.ToString()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When `object.ToString` is not overridden then it returns `object.GetType().ToString()`, which makes `object.ToString` return the fully qualified name of the type.
In case of the `ContentControl` (`ListBoxItem` is a `ContentControl`), `Control` provides the `object.ToString` override. `Control.ToString` actually creates the formatting you observe, composed of a the `object.GetType().ToString()` value of the current type and the `Content.ToString`value.

To remove the namespace, simply reference the `Content` property directly. You are interested in the value of the `Content` property so you must call `ToString` on this value.

Then to improve the performance of your UI do not repeatedly update the `TextBox` by concatenating its values. This is not efficient at all.
Instead use a `StringBuilder` to build the text value and update the `TextBox` once:

```cs
var textBoxValueBuilder = new SringBuilder();
foreach (ListBoxItem selectedItem in myListView.SelectedItems)
{
  string output = selectedItem.Content.ToString();
  textBoxValueBuilder.Append($"{output} ");
}

// Remove the trailing whitespace
textBoxValueBuilder.Remove(textBoxValueBuilder.Length - 1, 1);

string textBoxValue = textBoxValueBuilder.ToString();
tb.Text = textBoxValue; // Item1 Item2 Item2 ...
```